# How do I move the task bar to the default monitor in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I have a notebook running Windows 10 version 1803 (won't update to 1903, but that is another story) that I use either mobile, or at my desk. When at my desk, I run it with the lid closed, and 3 external monitors connected. Previously I used the click-n-drag method to relocate the taskbar to my default (middle) monitor.

Before you declare this a duplicate question, all of the other answers that I can find state that you can click-n-drag, and it worked - until about 3 weeks ago.

I can click-n-drag the other two occurrences of the taskbar around their respective monitors, but not between monitors. I cannot even drag the main taskbar around it's own monitor.

"Lock all taskbars" is not checked. I have even tried moving the taskbar with it checked, but as expected, that prevents any movement of the taskbars on any of the three monitors.

When I choose to Identify the monitors in Display Settings, the main taskbar is displaying on monitor 2. I'd currently be happy if the best I could achieve to have it fixed on monitor 1.

I have my left and right monitors orientated portrait, and my middle landscape, hence the offset levels of the taskbars in the linked image.

[Snipping tool capture showing display settings for 3 screens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6QGTV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on where you click to drag ...

When my main taskbar was on the secondary screen, there was no room  for me to click between the battery icon and the running processes, despite there being lots of blank space. When clicking on the arrow to scroll the running processes to row two, I can click in the space between the last process and the scroll arrows, and it all works as expected.

Shame there is not something saying "Don't click here to drag!!"

When it is on the main screen, I can click anywhere along the taskbar to move it -including right next to the battery icon. I love consistency. Oh boy.

Self answering in case it helps someone in the future.